# Alternative way to do Taylor series in C

Tags: c, taylor-series

In my class my professor wants us to use functions to solve a Taylor series for sinX, cosX and expX.

I solved it relatively fast but when I went to turn it in he said he wanted me to use division first instead of multiplication, basically combining my `power` and `fact` functions. I have no idea why he wants it done this way because I am getting the correct answer but he won't accept the assignment until I do it.

I tried several times to get my head around the solution but I'm not a Comp Sci major, and haven't taken math in 6+ years so its turning the gears in my brain pretty hard. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
double power(double x, int n)
{
    int     i = 0;
    double  prod = 1.;

    for ( ; i++ < n; )
        prod = prod * x;

    return prod;
}

double fact (int n)
{
    int     i;
    double prod = 1.;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        prod = prod * i;

    return prod;
}

double mySin(double x)
{
    int     i, sign;
    double  sum = 0;

    for (i = 0, sign = 1; i < 21; i++, sign = -sign)
        sum = sum + sign * power(x, 2 * i + 1)/ fact(2 * i + 1);
    return sum;
}

double myCos(double x)
{
    int     i, sign;
    double  sum = 0;

    for(i = 0, sign = 1; i < 21; i++, sign = -sign)
        sum = sum + sign *power(x,2 * i)/ fact(2 * i);
    return sum;
}

double myExp(double x)
{
    int     i, sign;
    double  sum = 0;

    for(i = 0, sign = 1; i < 21; i++, sign = sign)
        sum = sum + sign * power(x, i)/ fact(i);
    return sum;
 }
```

Comment: Hm... Parentheses around the division?

Comment: "I have no idea why he wants it done this way" - Did you ask?

Comment: Gotta love the "haven't taken math in +6 years so its turning the gears in my brain pretty hard" as I have not taken math in 6*6 years, yet the gears seem OK.

Comment: @chux Gears require some periodic maintenance.

Comment: You can optimize this a bit by calculating the exponent once, rather than in both the `power` and `fract` calls.  For instance in `mySin`, `int exp = 2 * i + 1;`  `sum = sum + sign * (power(x, exp) / fact(exp));`

Answer (score 4):

The use of the power and factorial functions is inefficient.  For each term, you're calculating the same set of products each time.  You're also building large numbers that can lead to loss of precision.

Take a look at the definition of each series (here `^` denotes power and `!` denotes factorial):

```
e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + x^4/4! + ...
sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - + x^7/7! + ...
cos(x) = 1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - + x^6/6! + ...
```

For `e^x`, each term is `x/n` times the last, where `n` is the term number.  Similarly, for `sin(x)` and `cos(x)`, each term is `- x^2/((2n-1)*2n)` times the last.  Use that instead of a power function and a factorial function to compute each successive term.

There's also a nice trick which involves a comparison which mathematically doesn't make sense but works because of the limited precision of floating point numbers to know when to stop calculating terms.  See if you can figure it out.

Comment: This approach may lead to numerical problems: adding very small numbers to a potentially large one loses precision quite early. Better do computation "inside out", aka https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method.

Comment: @user58697 That's part of the trick I mentioned.  Each successive term gets smaller until adding the term results in no change.  That's when you stop.

Comment: I think you miss my point. The sum of large and _very_ small number is inaccurate due to floating point underflow while normalizing. You should start summation adding small numbers first, that is right to left. The Horner method avoids dealing with very small numbers whatsoever.

Comment: @user58697 but using this method, there are no large numbers, since the power and factorial calculations are not needed.

Comment: @user58697 ...although I see what you mean. Perhaps the terms can be stored in an array and afterwards summed from right to left.

Comment: @WeatherVane If the function internally uses a larger type like `long double` (assuming it's larger) but returns a `double`, any precision error will be removed when cast to the smaller type.

Comment: @user58697 Adding right to left does help, but not by that much with `cos()`. I do  prefer to use that order.  I expect about 0.5 bit improvement - if that.  The trick, e.g. `cos()` is that even an early term like `x*x/2` contains a 0.5 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) error which is not recoverable using the "L-R" order.  I have tried various approaches with little improvement based on order.   With trig, I find reducing to the [0...pi/4] range a more useful improvement.